# Alien Invasion Highscore and Score problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

The highscore of my project so far is working, however, after my ship gets hit, the current score doesn't reset itself. For example, if I get 4000 points and my ship gets hit, during the next round, the highscore and current score is displayed as 4000 points. In this project I have the modules alien.py, alien_invasion.py, bullet.py, button.py, gamefunctions.py, game_stats.py, scoreboard.py, settings.py, and ship.py. However, I will only add the changes that the book tells you to do to have a highscore. Please feel free to ask if you would like to see more of the code

game_stats.py:

```
    class GameStats():
         def __init__(self, ai_settings):
              self.ai_settings = ai_settings
              self.reset_stats()
              self.game_active = False
              self.high_score = 0

         def reset_stats(self):
              self.ships_left = self.ai_settings.ship_limit
              self.score = 0
```

scoreboard.py:

```
    def show_score(self):
         self.screen.blit(self.score_image, self.score_rect)
         self.screen.blit(self.high_score_image, self.high_score_rect)
    def prep_high_score(self):
         high_score = int(round(self.stats.high_score, -1))
         high_score_str = "{:,}".format(high_score)
         self.high_score_image = self.font.render(high_score_str, True, self.text_color, 
              self.ai_settings.bg_color)
         self.high_score_rect = self.high_score_image.get_rect()
         self.high_score_rect.centerx = self.screen_rect.centerx
         self.high_score_rect.top = self.score_rect.top
```

game_functions.py:

```
    def check_high_score(stats, sb):
         if stats.score > stats.high_score:
             stats.high_score = stats.score
             sb.prep_high_score()
    def check_play_button(ai_settings, screen, stats, play_button, ship, 
    aliens, bullets, mouse_x, mouse_y):
         button_clicked = play_button.rect.collidepoint(mouse_x, mouse_y)
         if button_clicked and not stats.game_active:
              ai_settings.initialize_dynamic_settings()
              pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
              stats.reset_stats()
              stats.game_active = True
              aliens.empty()
              bullets.empty()
              create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
              ship.center_ship()
    def update_aliens(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
    check_fleet_edges(ai_settings, aliens)
        aliens.update()
        check_aliens_bottom(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens,                                 
        bullets)
        if pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(ship, aliens):
        print("Ship hit!!!")
        ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets)

    def ship_hit(ai_settings, stats, screen, ship, aliens, bullets):
        if stats.ships_left > 0:
             stats.ships_left -= 1
             stats.reset_stats()
             aliens.empty()
             bullets.empty()
             create_fleet(ai_settings, screen, ship, aliens)
             ship.center_ship()
             sleep(0.5)
       else:
            stats.game_active = False
            pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
```

Comment: Where is `score_image` created?  Is `reset_stats` called at each round?  Add a `print` statement to `reset_stats` to confirm when it is called.

Comment: How would I call `reset_stats` in `check_high_score`? If I write `self.reset_stats` and include self in the arguments of `check_high_score` it says the error `check_high_score() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Comment: Try `stats.reset_stats()`

Comment: I tried doing that and the score seems to lower every other time I hit an alien, and the highscore still doesn't reset after the ship gets hit.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem . But then I tried this :

I inserted a command "stats.score = 0" within the ship_hit function , so that the scoreand got done

Comment: Can you please explain why and how your fix worked?

Comment: As ship hit function causes the game to end , the comment "stats.score = 0" makes the score zero when the game ends . Just a guess (I am noob :))